# docker-compose—bind mount volume only in development

Tags: docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` like that:

```
version: '2'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/ll/stuff
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
```

That always mounts the volume, what is nice for development, but not for production. Is there a way to »tell« `docker-compose` to mount that volume only in development, or in other words, if `APP_ENV` is empty or `==development`?

Do I need to create another compose file for that? If so, can I use the configuration from the production file, without repeating stuff that does not change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From official docs: [Modify your compose file for production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#modify-your-compose-file-for-production)

> consider defining an additional Compose file, say production.yml, which specifies production-appropriate configuration. This configuration file only needs to include the changes you’d like to make from the original Compose file. The additional Compose file can be applied over the original docker-compose.yml to create a new configuration.
>
> Once you’ve got a second configuration file, tell Compose to use it with the -f option:
>
> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f production.yml up -d

it should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks, that's seam to be it! I will give it a shot!

Comment: Not sure how you would remove the mount rule, any idea? Or should we have a dedicated file for developement instead and only mount volumes in this file?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Create three files

Create one **common base file**, for both production and development: `docker-compose.yml`

Create another **file for development**, `docker-compose.development.yml`, for [extending](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/) or [merging](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/) the base file.

Create a third **file for production**, `docker-compose.production.yml`, for extending or merging the base file.

#### 2. Run docker compose

In *production* to *merge* these two files:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d
```

In *development* to *merge* these two files:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.development.yml up -d
```

This way, the risk is way smaller that development settings end up on production or vice versa.

---

#### More info

Great *merge* example here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/#example

Besides extend and merge, there is also a third choice, *include*:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/include/